# MySQL parametrized query with like operator

Tags: mysql, delphi

I am writing a query to get all the values from a column using the `like` operator from a MySQL database:

```
lQuery := 'select batch_id from batch where batch_id like =:BatchID';
DataModTM.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
DataModTM.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add(lQuery);
DataModTM.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('BatchID').Value :='%' + lbID + '%';
DataModTM.ADOQuery1.Active := true;
```

I tried the above way, but I am not getting any success.  Can someone please suggest the right way of doing it?

Comment: What problem are you having with it exactly?

Comment: Iam getting an error like Error in sql syntax near '=?'

Comment: You have an erroneous `=` after `like` in your SQL, you need to remove the `=`.

Comment: Thank Q @RemyLebeau Solved my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by @RemyLebeau: remove `=` from the query after the `like` keyword:

```
lQuery := 'select batch_id from batch where batch_id like :BatchID';
```